# How could I find my former private Ubuntu chat?

Tags: discussion

Recently I had a chat with someone here after I asked a question. Now, I need to find back that private discussion in order to check some of the solutions he gave me.

How could I find my former chat with him ?

Comment: This is probably better suited on META. Do you remember who you talked to and if it was in askubuntu general chat?

Comment: Yes, I remember of the name of the person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here it is.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14338/discussion-between-crasic-and-begueradj)

[image]

I searched for your name in our site's chat search box.

Comment: How did you find it, please ?

Comment: yes do explain the process. Or you do not get any upvotes (that always works @begueradj )